# Avoiding mapred.child.env modification at runtime on HDP so that R can establish connection to hiveserver2 using RHive

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to get R's RHive package to communicate nicely with hiveserver2.

I receive an error while trying to connect into hiveserver2 using:

```
>rhive.connect(host="localhost",port=10000, hiveServer2=TRUE, user="root", password="hadoop")
```

The output on the initial run:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/client/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/client/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/03/19 07:08:22 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/03/19 07:08:23 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
15/03/19 07:08:24 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: localhost:10000
15/03/19 07:08:24 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: localhost:10000
15/03/19 07:08:24 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

This leads to the error:

**Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify mapred.child.env at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime**

On subsequent runs of the same command the output reduces to:

```
15/03/19 07:16:24 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: localhost:10000
15/03/19 07:16:24 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: localhost:10000
15/03/19 07:16:24 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify mapred.child.env at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime
```

This indicates to me that I may have insufficient permissions somewhere... However, I'm running this using root. So, I'm unsure of what permissions I'm missing...

I've installed RHive using the installation guidelines [via README](https://github.com/nexr/RHive/blob/master/README.md).

**NOTE: The same error occurs if I use the [CRAN version of the package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHive/).**

I'm currently using [Hortonworks Data Platform 2.2 (HDP 2.2)](http://hortonassets.s3.amazonaws.com/2.2/Sandbox_HDP_2.2_VirtualBox.ova)'s virtual box image. As a result, hadoop and hiveserver2 are already installed. I've installed R version 3.1.2.

The following is how I am installing RHive:

```
# Set up paths for HIVE_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, and HADOOP_CONF
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hive

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf

# R Location via RHOME
R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R

# Place R_HOME into hadoop config location
sudo sh -c "echo \"R_HOME='$R_HOME'\" >> $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh"

# Add remote enable to Rserve config.
sudo sh -c "echo 'remote enable' >> /etc/Rserv.conf"

# Launch the daemon
R CMD Rserve

# Confirm launch
netstat -nltp

# Install ant to build java files
sudo yum -y install ant

# Install package dependencies
sudo R --no-save << EOF
install.packages( c('rJava','Rserve','RUnit'), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org', INSTALL_opts=c('--byte-compile') )
EOF

# Install RHive package
git clone https://github.com/nexr/RHive.git
cd RHive
ant build
sudo R CMD INSTALL RHive
```

To check either open R and use the statements between EOF or just run the command directly from shell:

```
sudo R --no-save << EOF
Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hive")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf")
library(RHive)
rhive.connect(host="localhost",port=10000, hiveServer2=TRUE, user="root", password="hadoop")
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is mentioned at this [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-ranger-user/201504.mbox/%3CD1418AFF.15EC3%25mneethiraj@hortonworks.com%3E).

Basically, you have to add a property "hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append" with value "mapred.child.env" in /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml

This solution worked for me, but I used Ambari UI to make this configuration change.

[image: Amabri UI (Hive Config tab) Screenshot]

Comment: This is very helpful.

Could you describe where in the Ambari UI you made the change?

I'm assuming under the Hive Services. Did you add it as a custom service?

Comment: Also, after I've made the change on HDP 2.2, the rhive.connect() function returns false. I'm unsure of how to make it return true.

Comment: @Coatless I added the property in hive configs tab -> Custom hive-site field, I edited my answer to include the screenshot.